# Can a subdomain also have a hostname?

Tags: networking, dns

For example, let say I have a subdomain name with the following IP address---> quality.com 12.1.1.2

Can I also use quality.com as a subdomain of book.quality.com?

What I'm trying to say is can, quality.com be use as a hostname and also as a subdomain?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. In your example, book.quality.com is a subdomain of quality.com. Domain hierarchies go from right (highest) to left (lowest).

Comment: I do not see how hostnames are related to that. A hostname is a name by which the computer locally identifies itself. It is not necessarily a domain name.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is can, quality.com be use as a hostname and also as a subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

A computer has a hostname and an IP address.

A subdomain is a collection of computers and IP addresses that share a common IP-address range and second- (or more) level domain name.

Your question is somewhat like asking "How do I get the roots off an apple?"  An apple doesn't have roots.  An apple sits on a tree.  The tree has roots.

Comment: There is absolutely no requirement for hosts within a subdomain to share an IP address range

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, domain name hierarchy goes from right to left.

subdomain.domain.com (i.e. book.quality.com - book is a subdomain of quality. Quality is a subdomain of com). Com is called the root zone.

When it comes to internet naming conventions these are all tied to DNS zones. Each domain can contain multiple records within a DNS zone that point to various IP addresses. So, you can add records for domain.com and you can add records for subdomain.domain.com.

If you want book.quality.com to be another sub-domain and be capable of having it's own A, MX, PTR, and other records then you will create a new zone in DNS. If book.quality.com simply points to a specific server then you will just create an A record for it in the quality.com zone. If the latter, then book would be a host entry in the DNS zone quality.com.

Despite the technicalities, a short answer to your question is that if you own quality.com you can create as many sub-domains and DNS zones as you want behind that. i.e. a.quality.com; b.quality.com; c.b.quality.com; more.c.b.quality.com